# Getting a custom jQuery tab system to work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, tabs

I am trying to develop a tab system for use in my web application. I understand the fundamentals of using tabs, and have managed to get working tab systems before.

This time, however, I need it to work slightly less conventionally. To begin with, all of the tab content is hidden. When I click on a tab, I want the content for the tab to slide down. Then, if I click on the same tab again, I want it to slide back up (thus hiding everything again). If I click on a different tab, though, I want to fade into the content for that tab.

This is the general appearance of it:

[image: The appearance of the user interface.]

Here is my HTML for the tabs:

```
<div class="controls">
    <ol class="sections">
        <li><a href="#touch"><img src="assets/img/touch.png" alt="Touch"> Touch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#speak"><img src="assets/img/speak.png" alt="Speak"> Speak</a></li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="actions" id="touch">
        <li><a href="#">Search for what hatched</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pick up the eggshell</a></li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="actions" id="speak">
        <li><a href="#">Call for what hatched</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pick up the eggshell</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

The HTML is laid out that way for styling reasons, so I'd rather not change that, if possible. The "sections" ordered list is for the tabs, and each "actions" is tab content for that tab.

This is my JavaScript (which does not work):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sections > li > a").click(function(){
        $("ol.actions").hide();
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
            $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        } else {
            $($(this).attr('href')).show();
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

I also tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sections li a").click(function(){
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        var parent = $(this).parent();

        var sections = $("ol.sections li");
        var actions = $("ol.actions");

        $(sections).removeClass("active");
        $(actions).slideUp();

        $(parent).addClass("active");
        $(target).slideDown();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Can anybody help me figure out the correct code for this? An example of a *similar* system is the accordion menu in jQuery UI, with the setting to make all of them collapsible but no more than one expandable at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built something similar before. You want to use the `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` jQuery methods.

EDIT:

Try this (again). (I made couple slight modifications. It was definitely broken before.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sections li a").click(function(){
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        var $parent = $(this).parent();

        var $sections = $("ol.sections li");
        var $actions = $("ol.actions");

        if( !$parent.hasClass('active') ){
            $sections.removeClass("active");
            $actions.slideUp();

            $parent.addClass("active");
            $(target).slideDown();
        } else {
            $sections.removeClass("active");
            $actions.slideUp();
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I have tried that previously. The problem was that each one would not close properly again.

Comment: BY not close properly, do you mean it doesn't animate? I would suspect it was a problem with your `active` class.

Comment: Well, it was more that everything worked fine, but as soon as I clicked on the current tab to minimize it again, it would slide up - but immediately bounce back down again.

Comment: I see. I think you need to check if the section you clicked has the `active` class before animating. If it does, skip the `slideDown()`.

Comment: (And the line above the `slideDown()`).

Comment: Ah - still not working (at all, now!). But I see the problem, I _think_. There is no default active tab?

Comment: I have complied with the website and moved this to chat :) [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34324/discussion-between-probabilitywolf-and-ryan-williams)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#touch").hide();
$("#speak").hide();

$(".sections > li > a").click(function(){
   var id=$(this).attr("href");
    $(".actions:visible").not(id).slideUp();
    if($(id).is(":visible"))  {      
        $(id).slideUp();}
    else
    {$(id).slideDown(); }

});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LY7rR/3/

Answer (score 0):

I successfully found the answer with this JavaScript:

```
$('#t1').click(function(){
    $('#touch').slideToggle('slow');
});
$('#t2').click(function(){
    $('#speak').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/LY7rR/4/) is the fiddle.